# Create a function in R to extract character from string by using position? The positions of characters are figured out based on pattern condition

Tags: r, string, extract

I want to create a function that extract characters from strings by using `substring`, but got some problems to find out the end_position to cut the character.

I got a string that stored in term of log file like that:

```
string = ("{\"country\":\"UNITED STATES\",\"country`_`code\":\"US\"}")
```

My idea is identify the position of each descriptions in the log and cut the character behind

```
start_position = as.numeric(str_locate(string,'\"country\":\"')[,2])
end_position = ??????
country = substring(x,start_position,end_postion)
```

The sign to recognize the end of character that I want to cut is the symbol `","` at the end. FOR EXAMPLE: `\"country\":\"UNITED STATES\",`

Could you guys tell me any way to get the position of `","` with condition of specific pattern in front? I intend to create a function later to extract character based on the recognized pattern. In this example, they are "country" and "country code"

Comment: Is this JSON? There are packages to handle it.

Comment: I tried it. However, my data is too big and using JSON gonna make it bigger. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using substring have a look into strsplit, that will split according to a pattern.

```
string = ("{\"country\":\"UNITED STATES\",\"country`_`code\":\"US\"})")

strsplit(string,",")[[1]][1]
[1] "{\"country\":\"UNITED STATES\""
```

You can change the pattern with every regex you like

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. The problem is my log file is so so big, it doesn't contain only 2 description like this but hundreds and I also have around thousand log files. I just want to substring what I want, not all the description inside

Comment: You just need to modify your splitpattern to be a regex that describes the split-positions you need. Alternatively you could gregexpr() for the positions and feed those to substr, but this is in the end the same with more functions

Comment: Could you show me how to do this? I try to use gregexpr() but can't identify both character "country" and "," to cut the pattern

Comment: im still not completely sure what you want, cause my solution should do exactly what you want. Can you give a reproducible example with the desired output you want?